# Есть ли такой модуль в Python

Tags: python, импорт

Есть ли модуль который определяет схожесть двух строк и учитывает синонимы ?

(Что-то по типу библиотеки FuzzyWuzzy)

Comment: Это куда-то в сторону эмбеддингов word2vec надо смотреть и считать косинусы углов между векторами. Но что считать синонимами сильно зависит от контекста, это уж на чём word2vec выучите. Нужно больше подробностей о задаче. Так то есть конечно и готовые эмбеддинги.

Comment: посмотрите  https://habr.com/ru/post/516098/

Comment: Синонимы я имею ввиду что-то по типу 
"Он красивый" = "Он привлекательный"

Answer (score 0):

PyDictionary что-то подобное может(но он действует в рамках определенного сайта с которого берет данные), вообще для такой задачи нужна как минимум нейросеть или даже полноценный ИИ.